# oracle regexp_like , specific number format without negative lookahead

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm using `regexp_like` function in Oracle in order to match the following number format : `xxxyxxx`

I'm trying this :

```
select 1 "val"
from   dual
where  regexp_like('5553555','^(\d){3}(?!\1)\d\1{3}$')
```

but as I realized, negative lookahead is not supported in Oracle.

how to do it without negative lookahead?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, no look around is possible. Please note that you also have another issue: `(\d){3}` will match also 3 *different* digits. You would need `(\d)\1\1` to match only three of the same digits.

For your particular case you could still use a regular expression. What I could think of is using a particular property: numbers with all the same 7 digits (xxxxxxx) will be dividable by 1111111.

With `regexp_like` and an additional modulo test:

```
with tbl(val) as  (
    select '5555555' from dual union
    select '5553555' from dual union
    select 'nothing' from dual
)
select val
from   tbl
where  regexp_like(val,'^(\d)\1\1\d\1{3}$') and mod(val, 1111111) > 0;
```

Or you could use two regexes:

```
with tbl(val) as  (
    select '5555555' from dual union
    select '5553555' from dual union
    select 'nothing' from dual
)
select val
from   tbl
where  regexp_like(val,'^(\d)\1\1\d\1{3}$') and not regexp_like(val,'^(\d)..\1');
```

Admittedly, neither is really elegant, and also not the most efficient. For more efficiency you should not use regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe *oldfashioned* `SUBSTR` might help. Something like this: split input string (`COL`) into two equal pieces, and compare whether they match. `LEN` is used to distinguish odd from even lengths and what to do with the second part of the string (i.e. which is its starting point).

A few examples:

```
SQL> WITH test (col) AS (SELECT '5554555' FROM DUAL),
  2       len AS (SELECT LENGTH (col) len FROM test)
  3  SELECT CASE
  4            WHEN SUBSTR (col, 1, TRUNC (LENGTH (col) / 2)) =
  5                    SUBSTR (
  6                       col,
  7                         TRUNC (LENGTH (col) / 2)
  8                       + CASE WHEN MOD (l.len, 2) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
  9            THEN
 10               'OK'
 11            ELSE
 12               'Not OK'
 13         END
 14            result
 15    FROM test t, len l;

RESULT
------
OK

SQL> l1
  1* WITH test (col) AS (SELECT '5554555' FROM DUAL),
SQL> c/5554/2234/
  1* WITH test (col) AS (SELECT '2234555' FROM DUAL),
SQL> /

RESULT
------
Not OK

SQL> l1
  1* WITH test (col) AS (SELECT '2234555' FROM DUAL),
SQL> c/2234555/1221/
  1* WITH test (col) AS (SELECT '1221' FROM DUAL),
SQL> /

RESULT
------
Not OK

SQL> l1
  1* WITH test (col) AS (SELECT '1221' FROM DUAL),
SQL> c/1221/8888/
  1* WITH test (col) AS (SELECT '8888' FROM DUAL),
SQL> /

RESULT
------
OK

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use of the Trim Function to Trim Off The 'X' Values from 'Y'**

This is just another approach to solving this subset of numeric palindrome problems.

If this were just a numeric palindrome, the undocumented function, reverse, could be used.  Since we have a `Y` for the midvalue and we are testing to make sure that `Y` is not equal to `X`, the reverse function does not help us a lot here.

Borrowing on the use of subexpressions (aka character grouping) approach that Trincot uses, I just create a second subexpression for the midvalue and then I trim off the midvalue.  If the trimmed expression is equal to original value, then we can be assured that `Y != X`.

```
SCOTT@db>WITH tst ( val ) AS (
  2      SELECT '5555555' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3      SELECT '12121' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4      SELECT '5553555' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5      SELECT 'amanaplanpanama' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6      SELECT '' FROM DUAL
  7  ) SELECT
  8      val,
  9      REGEXP_SUBSTR(val,'^(\d)\1\1(\d)\1{3}$',1,1,NULL,2) midval,
 10      TRIM(BOTH REGEXP_SUBSTR(val,'^(\d)\1\1(\d)\1{3}$',1,1,NULL,2) FROM val) trim_midval
 11    FROM
 12      tst
 13    WHERE
 14      1 = 1
 15      AND  val = TRIM(BOTH regexp_substr(val,'^(\d)\1\1(\d)\1{3}$',1,1,NULL,2) FROM val);

 -----------------------------
VAL       MIDVAL   TRIM_MIDVAL   
5553555   3        5553555       
 -----------------------------
```

Littlefoot's non-regular expression solution appears to be the most straightforward here.